# Ubuntu 12.04 shows Packages 404 not found while updating and Hash sum mismatch

Tags: upgrade, updates, update-manager

I'm getting the following error while updating:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-backports/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-backports/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-security_main_binary-i386_Packages  Hash Sum mismatch
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

If I try to update from update manager it shows: `Failed to download repository information
Check your Internet connection.`

I have absolutely no idea what to do next. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You are using Ubuntu 11.04 repositories on 12.04 which don't work. You can click the links in your question to see that even in your browser.

Go to Software Sources or Software and Updates, select Other software tab, select those two repositories and delete them.

You may want to restore your default repositories. Go to http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/ . Choose Precise, check main, restricted, universe, multiverse, security, updates, backports (both checkboxes for each). Click Generate at the bottom.

Open a terminal and type `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`. Put here what it was generated on the site I mentioned.

Do a `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: thanks man.I tried to put the default and updated again......But this time it's showing         W: Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-security_main_binary-i386_Packages  Hash Sum mismatch.  

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: What is showing? I don't understand what you meant to say.